# Show/Hide print button in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I was wondering is there any way to show print button based on the argument passed in the function. Here is my code that creates dialog box:

```
alertInfo: function (message, title, height, width, print) {
    $("<div></div>").dialog( {
        buttons: { 
            "Ok": function () { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            },
            //show/hide button if argument 'print' equals to 'Yes'
            "Print": function() { 
                $(this).dialog().printArea(); 
            }, 
        },
        close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: height,
            height: width,
            overflow:'auto',
            position: {
                 my: "center",
                 at: "center",
                 of: window
            }
    }).html(message);
}
```

This is the code where I'm passing the arguments in `alerInfo()` function:

```
$.alertInfo(infoTable,'User Info',800,600,'Yes');
```

I still did not get this to work and If I tried to put if statement around Print button error occurred. If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: What is "OK" and "print" in your code

Comment: @Geeky Ok and Print are buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
alertInfo: function(message, title, height, width, print) {
    var buttons = {
        "Ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    };
    if (print) buttons.print = function() {
        $(this).dialog().printArea();
    };
    $("<div></div>").dialog({
        buttons: buttons,
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        },
        resizable: false,
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        width: height,
        height: width,
        overflow: 'auto',
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: window
        }
    }).html(message);
}
```

This assumes the print parameter is a boolean

```
$.alertInfo(infoTable,'User Info',800,600, true); // to show print button

$.alertInfo(infoTable,'User Info',800,600, false); // to not show print button
```

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively passing an object to the `buttons` property:

```
{ 
    "Ok": function () { 
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
    },
    "Print": function() { 
        $(this).dialog().printArea(); 
    }
}
```

So what you can do is dynamically create that object based on your conditions and then set the dynamically created object to the property.  It might look something like this:

```
// create the object
var myButtons = {
    "Ok": function () { 
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
    }
};

// conditionally add a "print" button
if (someCondition) {
    myButtons.Print = function() { 
        $(this).dialog().printArea(); 
    }
}

// use the object
$("<div></div>").dialog( {
    buttons: myButtons,
    close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
    // etc.
});
```